# How do I test a Rails action with frozen strings as parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, testing, controller

I have an error in a Rails 4.2.7.1 controller action where I modify the incoming parameter:

```
params[:temperature].gsub!(',', '.')
```

Until recently this worked, but it fails in development and production now:

```
can't modify frozen String
```

**Update:** The cause of the frozen string is the comment at the top of the `application_controller.rb` file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

I have a fix for the problem, but I have no test that uncovers the error.  Both my controller test and integration test succeed with the faulty code, and I see that the parameters are not frozen in the controller even if they are frozen when posted from the test.

How can I ensure frozen parameters arrive in the controller in my test?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.3.1 and JRuby 9.1.5.0 with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your app in exactly the same way as regular use by using the [Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) gem and feature tests.  This uses an actual web browser to exercise your app.  It uncovered my error perfectly.

The downside is that it is *much* slower than a controller test or an integration test, by 10-100 times.